# Custom Colours in Color Picker

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using the inline editor for TinyMCE4 and I'm trying to replace the colours in the colour picker.

I've managed to do this using the following:

```
                    textcolor_map: [
                          "204292", "Pantone Blue 072",
                          "00a88F", "Pantone Green",
                          "F48C2D", "Pantone Orange 021",
                          "231F20", "Pantone Process Black" ,
                          "0095CE","Pantone Process Blue"
                    ],
```

The problem is, there is no more link to 'More Colors'. This option is availble in TinyMCE3, but not 4...

Has anyone come across this?

Thanks

Comment: +1 good question - let me know if you find a solution

Comment: It seems odd that it has been totally removed. I can't seem to find any reference to its removal in the documentation

Comment: please check here https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/196

Answer (score 0):

There's a custom plugin with for any custom color available at:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31419

Answer (score 0):

With the standard color picker, add the following in your init:

```
theme_concrete_text_colors : "436EB2,3CB54B,3b2315,ffffff,000000",
```

Replace concrete with the theme name, ie. theme_advanced_text_colors

http://youtu.be/hiaP3Y9wVdA